# How to install Azure cmdlets using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure, unattended-processing

I'm trying to install Azure cmdlets using powershell, not the wizard provided by Microsoft.

That's because my script (which has Azure cmdlets) will be used in a new virtual machine located in Azure and if my script try to run some cmdlet of Azure, will fail for sure.

I would like to put the installation lines of the powershell cmdlets on the top of my script for install the whole cmdlets and after that, that my script execute the other cmdlets without problem.

So, anyone knows?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Web Platform Installer in the VM, you can use the script I posted at PowerShell Magazine.

http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2014/02/27/using-powershell-and-web-platform-installer-to-install-azure-powershell-cmdlets/

Or get the Windows Standalone installer from https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases and use msiexec to install that.

If you want to use PowerShell to download the latest version too:

You can use `Invoke-WebRequest` to read the page (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases) and then get all links from that. You can then get all links that end with .msi and take the first link for download.

```
#Code not tested
$doc = Invoke-WebRequest 'https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-tools/releases' 
$links = $doc.Links.Href
```